# How to check a reference number uses a certain sequence of letters and number?

Tags: php, regex, validation

I have been given an assignment where I need to check if a Booking Reference is valid. The Booking Reference has to be in the style of "ABC-1234".
I need to use PHP to check the first three letters are either "ACT ABQ BDE". This is then followed by the "-". Then I need to check the numbers are in the following sequence, the first digit is either "1" or "2", and the following three digits are in the 0-9 range.
This is the code I currently have to check this:

```
 if (isset($webdata['bookingreference']  ))  {
  if (!preg_match("/^ [ACT] [ABQ] [BDE] - [(1),(2)]{5}[0-9]{6,}$/", $webdata['bookingreference']))  {
    $formerror['bookingreference'] = '<span class="warn" >Not valid on server: Invalid booking reference</span>';
    $valid = FALSE;
  }
```

However, when I test this, I always get the message it is valid no matter what the sequence is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go.

```
^(ACT|ABQ|BDE)-(1|2)[0-9]{3}$
```

`^(ACT|ABQ|BDE)` Means that it should start with the `ACT` or `ABQ` or `BDE`.

`-` sign means as is.

`(1|2)` should follow with one or two.

`[0-9]{3}$` means it should be a numeric from `0-9` and `{3}` it should be exactly three characters and `$` this is the end.

You can check it [here](https://regex101.com/r/YTLpcg/1).